# Android crop image using com.android.camera.action.CROP crash in HTC and Google Phone devices

Tags: android, image, crop, android-camera-intent

In my application user can select image from camera or gallery in android. 
After selecting image, user can also crop image from that original image. 
But after cropping, I am getting crash from that in HTC Desire 10 pro (Android 6.0) and Goolge Phone (Android 7.1.2).
I notices that these two devices are using Google Photos as their default Gallery.
In Samsung A5 (Android 6.0.1) and LG G5 (Android 7.0) devices it works fine.
I am using below code to crop image:

```
private void getPathImage(Uri picUri) {
    String picturePath = null;
    Uri filePathUri = picUri;
    if (picUri.getScheme().toString().compareTo("content")==0){
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(picUri,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
    }else if (picUri.getScheme().compareTo("file")==0){
        picturePath = filePathUri.getEncodedPath().toString();
    }
    performCropImage(picturePath);
}

private void performCropImage(String picUri) {
    try {
        //Start Crop Activity
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        File f = new File(picUri);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: post the stacktrace of exception, so that we can see where it occuring

Comment: Currently, i haven't HTC device. My partner test and get this bug. But he can't get log from HTC device. :( :( :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but please have a try to replace `cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");` with `cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);`.

Comment: you shouldn't use `com.android.camera.action.CROP`, as it is not mandatory for Android, but optional only. Not all devices support it. Instead implement your own crop functionality. Don't use what is not in the constants.